# Android bluetooth GATT connection limit per OS

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, limit, gatt

I have observed 7 simultaneous connections **max** on the Google Pixel6 Pro.  I have observed **at least** 8 simultaneous connections on the S23 (I have only 8 devices that utilize GATT).

I would like to compile a list of Android phones in terms of max GATT simultaneous connections.  I believe I am in search of documents stating the max connection count per Android OS version.  But, I have only found the open-source Android with `BTA_GATTC_CONN_MAX = GATT_MAX_PHY_CHANNEL = 7` here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/master/include/bt_target.h
and here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/android-9.0.0_r7/bta/gatt/bta_gattc_int.h

Anyone know where I might look for this info?  I have checked SO, individual phone release statements, Wiki, and Android SDK doc to no avail.  Hopefully, I just overlooked something...

Comment: More FYI: [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cdd) generally defines what capabilities are required for a device on its release OS version to get the Google Play Store/Services. See: [Android 14 CDD Bluetooth](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/14/android-14-cdd#743_bluetooth) and note the revisions from prior versions (probably for TV & Automotive versions).